# What is the Proper Way to Get the Calling Sheet from xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I've been using `RunPython` for awhile now with the below structure from Excel VBA

```
Sub GetModel()
    RunPython ("from [...] import fill_model; fill_model()") 
End Sub
```

The python function looks like the below which used to work until I updated to xlwings 0.15.6.

```
from xlwings.main import Book

def fill_model():
    wb = Book.caller()
```

Now I get the following exception  when running from Excel:

> Exception: Book.caller() must not be called directly. Call through Excel or set a mock caller first with Book.set_mock_caller().

However, this is not a mock caller setting as I'm calling from excel.  I understand I could use a call like `wb = Book('name_of_sheet.xlsm')` but sometimes the users rename the sheet when they are using it.  What is the right way to get the calling sheet?

Comment: I checked that both the python package and the addin were the same version 0.15.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ['vba'](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#the-vba-keyword) keyword when defining a argument and then use the VBA object for the active sheet name like so:

```py
@xw.sub
@xw.arg('active_sheet', vba='ActiveSheet.Name')
def my_macro(active_sheet):
    sheet = xw.Book.caller().sheets[active_sheet]
    sheet.range('A1').value = 'hello world'
```